# MD5 in Java different from MD5sum in shell

Tags: java

I'm trying to generate an MD5 hash using Java and Shell but the problem is I get different results using :

```
    public String generateHash(String name) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    MessageDigest digester = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    digester.update(name.getBytes());
    byte[] md5Bytes = digester.digest();
    String md5Text = null;

    md5Text = bytesToHex(md5Bytes);

    return md5Text;
}

    public static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
    char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
    for (int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++) {
        int v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
        hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
        hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
    }
    return new String(hexChars);
}
```

and using :

```
md5sum
```

How can I get the same result as the "md5sum" command in Java ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under the assumption that

```java
private static final char[] hexArray = "0123456789abcdef".toCharArray();
```

both methods, i.e. you program and `md5sum`, produce the same result. Be careful to not accidentaly add any newlines.

You can compare the result of both of these example to check that you get the same output:

```java
System.out.println(generateHash("ABCDEF"));
System.out.println(generateHash("ABCDEF\n"));
```

```sh
echo -n  "ABCDEF" | md5sum
echo "ABCDEF" | md5sum
```

**Output:**

```
8827a41122a5028b9808c7bf84b9fcf6
f6674e62795f798fe2b01b08580c3fdc
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem. I didn't notice that I had a "\n" in my String in Java.